# Best ways to manage generated artifacts for web service/xml bindings in a java webapp/client?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, maven-2, jaxb

I'm working on a couple of web services that use JAXB bindings for the messages (in JAX-WS or spring-ws). When using these bindings there's always some code that is automatically generated from the WSDL to bind the message objects. I'm struggling to figure out the best way I can make this work so that it's easy to work with, hard to break and integrates nicely with IDEs (mostly using eclipse).

I think there are a couple of ways to go about this. The three main options I see right now are:

- Generate code, keep the source artifacts and check them into the repository. Pros: integrates easily with IDEs (source highlighting etc), works within the build system. Cons: generated code changes each time you regenerate it, possibly creating noisy commits. It's also redundant since the WSDL file is already checked in, usually.
- Generate code as part of the build process. Don't keep source artifacts or only keep them in output directories. Pros: fixes all the cons from the previous one. Cons: harder to integrate with IDE, though maybe this build step can be run automatically? I currently use this on one of my projects but the first time I checkout the project it appears broken, which is a minor nuisance.
- Keep generated bindings in separate libraries (jars) included with maven or manually updated jars, depending on your build process. I got the idea from [a thread on java.net](http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=254526). This seems more stable and uses explicit versioning but seems a bit heavyweight.

Which one of these options would you implement and how? We're currently using maven and eclipse, so any ideas in that regard would be great. I think this problem generalises to most other build systems and IDE combinations though, even other languages perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for option 2 and generate code in the "standard" `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/<toolname>` location as part of the build process. Using generated sources is well supported by m2eclipse (use **Maven > Update Project Configuration** once sources have been generated) and, if I remember well, by the [maven eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) as well (i.e. the folder will be added to the **Java Build Path**). Actually, I think [NetBeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices) also handle this fine. Not sure for Idea.

For the generation itself, you may need the [maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://maven-jaxb2-plugin.dev.java.net/) if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I went for option 3. If you already host your own repository (and optionally CI), it's not that heavyweight. All it takes is a simple POM. It's even possible to include some utility/wrapper/builder classes (that often make life easier with generated classes) and use them in several projects.