# Maven doesn't compile target/hibernate3/generated-sources

Tags: hibernate, maven-2, hibernate3, hbm2java

Can someone tell me how to configure maven for it also to compile sources from the `target/hibernate3/generated-sources` directory? I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900234/maven-java-source-code-generation-for-hibernate) and other posts but they don't seem to solve my problem (which indeed seems trivial).

I have used the bottom-up approach hibernate configuration for cfg.xml, hbm.xml and POJO generation (i.e. auto-generated the complete hibernate configuration out of an existing database schema). I'm also only using standard `maven` and `hibernate3-plugin` directory layouts. Yet, when executing `mvn compile` in the command-line while my sources are in the `src/main/java` and the generated sources in `/target/hibernate3/generated-sources` only the ones from `src/main/java` get compiled and copied into `target/classes`. I wouldn't like to generate sources into `src/main/java` as I'd like `mvn clean` to clean them.

I'd like to solve the problem using `command-line`, `plugins` and `pom.xml` only. Is there a way to configure `maven-compiler-plugin` to do so? Or is there another way?

Regards and thanks for any help.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? do you want to exclude some files from your .jar?

Comment: Actually, the "target directory" part was a bit out of the scope of my previous answer but I realize it can be misleading and I'll clarify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The convention is to generate code in `target/generated-sources/<generator>` so in your case, I would generate sources in `target/generated-sources/hibernate3` (it's sad the hibernate3 plugin doesn't follow this convention by default). Anyway, things should work and actually, the POM I posted in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848567/how-to-configure-hbm2java-and-hbm2dao-to-add-packagename-to-generated-classes/2852173#2852173) does (I re-ran my sample project and it definitely works). Could you be a victim of [MHIBERNATE-104](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MHIBERNATE-104)? Honestly, I'm confused.

As a workaround, you could use the [Build Helper Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) and its [`build-helper:add-source`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html) goal to add your directory as source directory. See the [Usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) page for a configuration example.

---

> I'm using exactly the pom you proposed here, just not plugged into the default build lifecycle (without executions).

That must be the cause of the problem: if `hibernate3:hbm2java` isn't part the build lifecycle, it doesn't get the opportunity to register the output directory as source folder. So Maven isn't aware of it during the "normal build" and will just ignore it.

Comment: +1 @Pascal Thivent can you use this while generating classes from xml schema?

Comment: @Pascal: thanks for your answer. What really confuses me, is that the default directory `target/hibernate3/generated-sources` is not the convention. I have just checked, and none of those two directories work out of the box, still only `src/main/java` get compiled. Maybe I screwed something else up, but I'll try the second solution anyway, this should work without problems.

Comment: @c0mrade: Yes, you can (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857081/how-can-i-tell-jaxb-maven-to-genereate-multiple-schema-packages/2857613#2857613), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556442/maven-jaxb2xjc-jaxwswsimport-to-be-added-in-eclipse) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295025/best-ways-to-manage-generated-artifacts-for-web-service-xml-bindings-in-a-java-we/2295146#2295146)).

Comment: @mmm That's extremely weird. The solution I posted in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848567/how-to-configure-hbm2java-and-hbm2dao-to-add-packagename-to-generated-classes/2852173#2852173) works *as is*. I double checked with another project on my machine that uses this configuration and confirm it definitely works. Just in case, what version of the plugin do you use?

Comment: @Pascal: thanks a lot again. [MHIBERNATE-104](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MHIBERNATE-104) can indeed be the case. With the `Build Helper Maven Plugin` everything seems ok, though. Actually, without it, even the `m2eclipse -> Update Project Configuration` option didn't work (??), though this can be unrelated. BTW.: I'm using exactly the pom you proposed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848567/how-to-configure-hbm2java-and-hbm2dao-to-add-packagename-to-generated-classes/2852173#2852173), just not plugged into the default build lifecycle (without executions).

Comment: @Pascal: I'm using version `2.2` of `hibernate3-maven-plugin`

Comment: @mmm: BTW, I created an issue for the default outputDirectory (see [MHIBERNATE-106](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MHIBERNATE-106)) and it appears that it will be fixed in version 3.0.

Comment: @Pascal: Regarding unplugging `hibernate3:hbm2java` from the build lifecycle and then maven not knowing about the generated sources in the normal build: thanks again... :).